# QGraphicsTextItem can not change Input Method in 64bit version

Tags: python, pyqt, 64-bit

I am using pyqt5.4.2-x64 + python3.4 64bit.
Unfortunately the QGraphicsTextItem can not change Input Method, In the demo in example/widgets/graphicsview/digramscene, the QGraphicsTextItem can only accept ascii character, I can not input chinese to it.
But if I switch to 32bit version, there is no problem.
do you have a solution?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke the method provided by QGraphicsItem like this:

```
QGraphicsItem::setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemAcceptsInputMethod, true);
```

Even more, if you inherited from QGraphicsTextItem or something, please override the keyReleaseEvent in order to propagate event right to the parent. By this way, you'll do the job. It looks like this:

```
void YourGraphicsItem::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
    QGraphicsTextItem::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```